# Login script, cookie saved wrong pass?

Tags: php, mysql, session, cookies, authentication

I have this easy to use login for my page wich i have been using a long time.

Now im trying to modify it abit so that my username and password is stored in a database instead of in clear text in the file.

The password is stored with MD5 in the database and the login works fine, but when i enter a site where you have to be logged in i get re-directed into the login screen where it says wrong password...

what am i doing wrong?

```
<?php
$un = $_POST['user'];
require_once ('/inc/login_conn.php');
    $dsn = "mysql:Server=$Lhost:$Lport;Database=$Ldb";
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserName= '$un'";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute ();
    $sett1= $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$user = $sett1['UserName'];
$pass = $sett1['Password'];

define('LOGIN_USER', "$user");
//define('LOGIN_USER', "USERNAME");
define('LOGIN_PASS', "$pass");
//define('LOGIN_PASS', "PASSWORD");
class Login {
    // unique prefix that is used with this object (on cookies and password salt)
    var $prefix = "login_";
    // days "remember me" cookies will remain
    var $cookie_duration = 1;
    var $user = "";
    var $pass = "";
    function authorize() {

    //save cookie info to session
        if(isset($_COOKIE[$this->prefix.'user'])){
            $_SESSION[$this->prefix.'user'] = $_COOKIE[$this->prefix.'user'];
            $_SESSION[$this->prefix.'pass'] = $_COOKIE[$this->prefix.'pass'];
        }
    //  else{echo "no cookie<br>";}


    //if setting vars
        if(isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == "set_login"){

            $this->user = $_POST['user'];
        $this->pass = md5($this->prefix.md5($_POST['pass'])); //hash password. salt with prefix

        $this->check();//dies if incorrect

        //if "remember me" set cookie
        if(isset($_POST['remember'])){
            setcookie($this->prefix."user", $this->user, time()+($this->cookie_duration*86400));// (d*24h*60m*60s)
            setcookie($this->prefix."pass", $this->pass, time()+($this->cookie_duration*86400));// (d*24h*60m*60s)
        }

        //set session
        $_SESSION[$this->prefix.'user'] = $this->user;
        $_SESSION[$this->prefix.'pass'] = $this->pass;
    }

    //if forced log in
    elseif(isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == "prompt"){
        session_unset();
        session_destroy();
        //destroy any existing cookie by setting time in past
        if(!empty($_COOKIE[$this->prefix.'user'])) setcookie($this->prefix."user", "blanked", time()-(3600*25));
        if(!empty($_COOKIE[$this->prefix.'pass'])) setcookie($this->prefix."pass", "blanked", time()-(3600*25));

        $this->prompt();
    }

    //if clearing the login
    elseif(isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == "clear_login"){
        session_unset();
        session_destroy();
        //destroy any existing cookie by setting time in past
        if(!empty($_COOKIE[$this->prefix.'user'])) setcookie($this->prefix."user", "blanked", time()-(3600*25));
        if(!empty($_COOKIE[$this->prefix.'pass'])) setcookie($this->prefix."pass", "blanked", time()-(3600*25));

        $msg = '<h2 class="msg">**Logout complete**</h2>';
        $this->prompt($msg);
    }

    //prompt for
    elseif(!isset($_SESSION[$this->prefix.'pass']) || !isset($_SESSION[$this->prefix.'user'])){
        $this->prompt();
    }

    //check the pw
    else{
        $this->user = $_SESSION[$this->prefix.'user'];
        $this->pass = $_SESSION[$this->prefix.'pass'];
        $this->check();//dies if incorrect
    }

}#-#authorize()

function check(){

    if(md5($this->prefix . LOGIN_PASS) != $this->pass || LOGIN_USER != $this->user){
        //destroy any existing cookie by setting time in past
        if(!empty($_COOKIE[$this->prefix.'user'])) setcookie($this->prefix."user", "blanked", time()-(3600*25));
        if(!empty($_COOKIE[$this->prefix.'pass'])) setcookie($this->prefix."pass", "blanked", time()-(3600*25));
        session_unset();
        session_destroy();

        $msg='<h2 class="warn">Incorrect username or password</h2>';
        $this->prompt($msg);
    }
}#-#check()
function prompt($msg=''){
    ?>
```

Session:

```
<?php

session_start(); 
require("/Login.class.php");
$login = new Login;

$login->authorize(); 

?>
```

EDIT:

If i change the line

```
 $this->pass = md5($this->prefix.md5($_POST['pass'])); //hash password. salt with prefix
```

To as it were before i tried to get my username and pw from db:

```
$this->pass = md5($this->prefix.$_POST['pass']); //hash password. salt with prefix
```

and log in with my hashed password, it still does not seem to work.... so might the problem be somewhere else? if i set define_user and define_pass to static vars it works like a charm...

Comment: try displaying `echo md5($this->prefix . LOGIN_PASS) .' != '.$this->pass.' || '.LOGIN_USER.' != '.$this->user`

Comment: @Beginner oh wait, b7917109458bf9b466f4cbbffdd7bf87 != 5eaf12a1b336deba86e0ee94817c5be3 || != root

Comment: put that before condition

Comment: @Beginner edited my comment, however the pass should be fde02ddf8aaadbe8c88c2c8f929ed861, root is the account im logging in with

Comment: your value in db is fde02ddf8aaadbe8c88c2c8f929ed861 ?

Comment: @Beginner yes it is

Comment: can you include you encryption pattern when you register?

Comment: i have just done like this: $pass =  $_POST['password'];
$password = md5($pass);

Comment: Hi can you try compare them `echo md5($_POST['pass']).' == '.LOGIN_PASS`

Comment: @Beginner compare to what?

Comment: oh ok, from that line i get d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e == jesus im in way over my head for sure..

Comment: I see not encrypted.
try `echo $sett1['Password'];` after your query

Comment: that gives me the correct string: fde02ddf8aaadbe8c88c2c8f929ed861

Comment: am in encrypting the already encrypted string or something?

Comment: @Beginner if i change line 37 to $this->pass = $this->prefix.md5($_POST['pass']); //hash password. salt with prefix i get the following from the lines that you have asked me to try: fde02ddf8aaadbe8c88c2c8f929ed861 == fde02ddf8aaadbe8c88c2c8f929ed861
5eaf12a1b336deba86e0ee94817c5be3 login_fde02ddf8aaadbe8c88c2c8f929ed861 || root root But it says wrong password when i try to login

Comment: Anyone? i cant get this to work as intented...